# MySQL saving UTF-8 entries from PHP correctly in VARCHAR but not in text blobs

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I current have the following snippet of text in a text paragraph for my website

```
let’s get to it
```

The apostrophe character is part of the UTF-8 charset, and it saves properly in a table column that is designated a VARCHAR column, in the form

```
 letâ€™s get to it
```

Which is properly parsed by my client. If I put the same text into a TEXT column in MySQL, it's stored as the following:

```
let&acirc;&#128;&#153;s get to it.
```

Is there any reason the two would differ, and if so, how can I change it?

Comment: Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`, or at least the relevant parts where the charset is set.

Comment: check your field collation. Anyway `ALTER TABLE t MODIFY text_field TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: The `letâ€™s` doesn't look as UTF-8 to me. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`letâ€™s` is Mojibake.  Latin1 is creeping in.

"text blob" -- which is it `TEXT` or `BLOB`?  They are *different* datatypes.

`let&acirc;&#128;&#153;s` comes from `htmlentities()` or something equivalent.  That can be stored and retrieved in `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, or `BLOB`, regardless of `CHARACTER SET`.  MySQL will *not* convert to that.

The Mojibake *probably* came from

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.